# XSLT 1.0 if, for each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

can you help me please.

I´d like to have from my XML two infos.

1. If Qualifier CN (at ADD) add CONTACT/NUMBER to GRP
2. If Qualifier ST (at ADD) add PARTY_NAME_1,... to GRP

I tried following XSLT: (but please find below my answer with new XSLT, if it´s correct?)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
  
   <xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:copy>
 <!--copy the data from ADD - CN to the GRP so it can be used in the mapping to set the contact from end customer-->
      <xsl:for-each  select ="./ADD">
  <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='CN'">          
    <CONTACT_NUMBER>
     <xsl:value-of select="CONTACT/NUMBER"/>
    </CONTACT_NUMBER>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
     <!--copy all other nodes-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
     <xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:copy>
 <!--copy the data from ADD - ST to the GRP so it can be used in the mapping to set the delivery address from end customer-->
      <xsl:for-each  select ="./ADD">
  <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='ST'">
          <xsl:copy-of select="PARTY_NAME_1"/>    
          <xsl:copy-of select="STREET_1"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="CITY"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="POSTAL_CODE"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="COUNTRY_CODE"/>    
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
     <!--copy all other nodes-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!--delete IC node-->
  <xsl:template match="IC" />
  
  <!--delete FILTER_SET node-->
  <xsl:template match="FILTER_SET" />
 
  <!--delete SEE_AG node-->
  <xsl:template match="SEE_AG" />

  <!--delete ME node-->
  <xsl:template match="ME" />

  <!--delete REF node-->
  <xsl:template match="REF" />
  
  <!--delete TRANSPORT_DETAILS node-->
  <xsl:template match="TRANSPORT_DETAILS" />
  
  <!--delete PACKAGE_DETAILS node-->
  <xsl:template match="PACKAGE_DETAILS" />
  
  <!--delete AMOUNT_DETAILS node-->
  <xsl:template match="AMOUNT_DETAILS" />
  
   <!-- delete empty nodes -->
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
<!-- delete empty nodes -->  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here´s my XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SEEDELFOR>
 <SEE_AG COPYRIGHT="" CREATION_DATE="2007-05-09" MESSAGE="" MAPPING="" VERSION="1.1.54"/>
 <CNT>
  <TRANSMISSION_DATE>20181024</TRANSMISSION_DATE>
  <TRANSMISSION_TIME>060300</TRANSMISSION_TIME>
  <INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER>1240</INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER>
  <SENDER></SENDER>
  <SENDER_QUALIFIER>14</SENDER_QUALIFIER>
  <RECEIVER></RECEIVER>
  <RECEIVER_QUALIFIER>14</RECEIVER_QUALIFIER>
  <SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER>UNOC</SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER>
  <SYNTAX_VERSION>3</SYNTAX_VERSION>
  <GRP>   
   <IDENTIFIER_BY></IDENTIFIER_BY>
   <IDENTIFIER_MF></IDENTIFIER_MF>
   <IDENTIFIER_ST></IDENTIFIER_ST>
   <IDENTIFIER_SU></IDENTIFIER_SU>
   <IDENTIFIER_UD></IDENTIFIER_UD>
   <IDENTIFIER_CA></IDENTIFIER_CA>
   <DATE_4></DATE_4>
   <REF_ON></REF_ON>
   <TXT_001>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <TEXT_LINE></TEXT_LINE>
   </TXT_001>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1></PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1></STREET_1>
    <CITY></CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE></POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1></PARTY_NAME_1>
    <CITY></CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE></POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1></PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1></STREET_1>
    <CITY></CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE></POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER>CN</QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1>Name</PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1>Street</STREET_1>
    <CITY>City</CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE>12345</POSTAL_CODE>
    <COUNTRY_CODE>DE</COUNTRY_CODE>
    <CONTACT>
     <QUALIFIER>TE</QUALIFIER>
     <NUMBER>012345/6789_CN</NUMBER>
    </CONTACT>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1></PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1></STREET_1>
    <CITY></CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE></POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER>ST</QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1>Name_ST</PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1>Street_ST</STREET_1>
    <CITY>City_ST</CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE>12345_ST</POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
    <ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <DETAILS></DETAILS>
    </ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
   </TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
   <ITEM>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_EN></ITEM_NUMBER_EN>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_IN></ITEM_NUMBER_IN>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_SA></ITEM_NUMBER_SA>
    <QUANTITY></QUANTITY>
    <QUANTITY_UNIT></QUANTITY_UNIT>
    <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER></LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>
    <AMOUNT_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <AMOUNT></AMOUNT>
     <CURRENCY></CURRENCY>
    </AMOUNT_DETAILS>
    <REF>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <REF>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <REF>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <PACKAGE_DETAILS>
     <NUMBER_OF_PACKAGES></NUMBER_OF_PACKAGES>
     <REF>
      <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
      <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     </REF>
     <REF>
      <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
      <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     </REF>
    </PACKAGE_DETAILS>
   </ITEM>
  </GRP>
 </CNT>
</SEEDELFOR>
```

Correct Output should be:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SEEDELFOR>
 <SEE_AG COPYRIGHT="" CREATION_DATE="2007-05-09" MESSAGE="" MAPPING="" VERSION="1.1.54"/>
 <CNT>
  <TRANSMISSION_DATE>20181024</TRANSMISSION_DATE>
  <TRANSMISSION_TIME>060300</TRANSMISSION_TIME>
  <INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER>1240</INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER>
  <SENDER></SENDER>
  <SENDER_QUALIFIER>14</SENDER_QUALIFIER>
  <RECEIVER></RECEIVER>
  <RECEIVER_QUALIFIER>14</RECEIVER_QUALIFIER>
  <SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER>UNOC</SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER>
  <SYNTAX_VERSION>3</SYNTAX_VERSION>
  <GRP>
   <CONTACT_NUMBER>012345/6789_CN</CONTACT_NUMBER>
   <PARTY_NAME_1>Name_ST</PARTY_NAME_1>
   <STREET_1>Street_ST</STREET_1>
   <CITY>City_ST</CITY>
   <POSTAL_CODE>12345_ST</POSTAL_CODE>
   <IDENTIFIER_BY></IDENTIFIER_BY>
   <IDENTIFIER_MF></IDENTIFIER_MF>
   <IDENTIFIER_ST></IDENTIFIER_ST>
   <IDENTIFIER_SU></IDENTIFIER_SU>
   <IDENTIFIER_UD></IDENTIFIER_UD>
   <IDENTIFIER_CA></IDENTIFIER_CA>
   <DATE_4></DATE_4>
   <REF_ON></REF_ON>
   <TXT_001>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <TEXT_LINE></TEXT_LINE>
   </TXT_001>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1></PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1></STREET_1>
    <CITY></CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE></POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1></PARTY_NAME_1>
    <CITY></CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE></POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1></PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1></STREET_1>
    <CITY></CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE></POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER>CN</QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1>Name</PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1>Street</STREET_1>
    <CITY>City</CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE>12345</POSTAL_CODE>
    <COUNTRY_CODE>DE</COUNTRY_CODE>
    <CONTACT>
     <QUALIFIER>TE</QUALIFIER>
     <NUMBER>012345/6789_CN</NUMBER>
    </CONTACT>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1></PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1></STREET_1>
    <CITY></CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE></POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER>ST</QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <PARTY_NAME_1>Name_ST</PARTY_NAME_1>
    <STREET_1>Street_ST</STREET_1>
    <CITY>City_ST</CITY>
    <POSTAL_CODE>12345_ST</POSTAL_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
    <ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <DETAILS></DETAILS>
    </ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
   </TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
   <ITEM>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_EN></ITEM_NUMBER_EN>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_IN></ITEM_NUMBER_IN>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_SA></ITEM_NUMBER_SA>
    <QUANTITY></QUANTITY>
    <QUANTITY_UNIT></QUANTITY_UNIT>
    <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER></LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>
    <AMOUNT_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <AMOUNT></AMOUNT>
     <CURRENCY></CURRENCY>
    </AMOUNT_DETAILS>
    <REF>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <REF>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <REF>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     <ADDITIONAL_INFO/>
    </REF>
    <PACKAGE_DETAILS>
     <NUMBER_OF_PACKAGES></NUMBER_OF_PACKAGES>
     <REF>
      <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
      <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     </REF>
     <REF>
      <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
      <REFERENCE></REFERENCE>
     </REF>
    </PACKAGE_DETAILS>
   </ITEM>
  </GRP>
 </CNT>
</SEEDELFOR>
```

Thanks, best regards
Julian

Comment: The two templates that you show us conflict - and only the last of them will be executed (if at all). -- P.S. Please read: [mcve].

Comment: ok thanks, do you need my full xml and xslt? i need both outputs...

Comment: No, we need the **minimum** code (XML + XSLT + expected result) required to reproduce the problem. -- If you need both outputs, why not have a single template produce them?

Comment: i added now xml and xslt. yes, if this the correct way, i can try a single template. but i don´t know why. so please i need help.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the expected output? Thank you.

Comment: i have added, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
  
      <xsl:template match="GRP">
    <xsl:copy>
 <!--copy the data from ADD - ST to the GRP so it can be used in the mapping to set the delivery address from end customer-->
      <xsl:for-each  select ="./ADD">
  <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='ST'">
          <xsl:copy-of select="PARTY_NAME_1"/>    
          <xsl:copy-of select="STREET_1"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="CITY"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="POSTAL_CODE"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="COUNTRY_CODE"/>    
        </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="./QUALIFIER='CN'">
    <CONTACT_NUMBER>
     <xsl:value-of select="CONTACT/NUMBER"/>
    </CONTACT_NUMBER>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
     <!--copy all other nodes-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!--delete IC node-->
  <xsl:template match="IC" />
  
  <!--delete FILTER_SET node-->
  <xsl:template match="FILTER_SET" />
 
  <!--delete SEE_AG node-->
  <xsl:template match="SEE_AG" />

  <!--delete ME node-->
  <xsl:template match="ME" />

  <!--delete REF node-->
  <xsl:template match="REF" />
  
  <!--delete TRANSPORT_DETAILS node-->
  <xsl:template match="TRANSPORT_DETAILS" />
  
  <!--delete PACKAGE_DETAILS node-->
  <xsl:template match="PACKAGE_DETAILS" />
  
  <!--delete AMOUNT_DETAILS node-->
  <xsl:template match="AMOUNT_DETAILS" />
  
   <!-- delete empty nodes -->
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
<!-- delete empty nodes -->  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```